# Python Requests Module: Failing to retrieve full response

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

I am trying to connect with A Broadsoft OCI-P which accepts XML to CRUD user subscriptions etc.
My required action is an authentication request where I request login, I receive a nonce, generate an MD5 response and then would be allowed continue.
I send initial request and I can see the Nonce arrive back via tcpdump (wireshark). Neither python requests or httplib2 receive the full response with the nonce. (I have managed the full authentication using bash.)

Has anyone got any ideas as to why I am not receiving the full response? Is it the '\n' in the response? If so, what can I do about it?

Thanks
M

```
try: 
    print('Using the Requests Module') 
    headers={'cache-control':'no-cache', 'Accept-Encoding':'ISO-8859-1', 'content-type':'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1','Accept': 'application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*', } 
    encoded_body = make_payload() 
    r = requests.post('http://10.*.*.*:2208', data = encoded_body,\
       headers = headers, auth = ('admin', 'admin')) 
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<BroadsoftDocument protocol = "OCI" xmlns="C" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<sessionId xmlns="">DJ1U3ZFW54J9068R1YDNOE0CNSICCTJS</sessionId> 
<command xsi:type="AuthenticationRequest" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
<userId>admin</userId> 
</command>
</BroadsoftDocument>

('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>\n',))
```

Trace on Wireshark from originating machine shows:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.*.*.*:2208
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: ISO-8859-1
Accept: application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.12.4
content-type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
cache-control: no-cache
Content-Length: 376
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<BroadsoftDocument protocol = "OCI" xmlns="C" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
<sessionId xmlns="">DJ1U3ZFW54J9068R1YDNOE0CNSICCTJS</sessionId>  
<command xsi:type="AuthenticationRequest" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
<userId>admin</userId>  
</command>
</BroadsoftDocument>
```

## RESPONSE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<BroadsoftDocument protocol="OCI" xmlns="C" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<sessionId xmlns="">DJ1U3ZFW54J9068R1YDNOE0CNSICCTJS</sessionId>
<command echo="" xsi:type="AuthenticationResponse" xmlns="">
<userId>admin</userId>
<nonce>1483616534128</nonce>
<passwordAlgorithm>MD5</passwordAlgorithm>
</command>
```

I get a similar error with httplib2:

```
send: 'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 10.xxx.xxx.198:2208\r\nContent-Length: 376\r\nuser-agent: Python-httplib2/0.9.2 (gzip)\r\ncontent-type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\naccept-encoding: ISO-8859-1\r\naccept: application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*\r\ncache-control: no-cache\r\n\r\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<BroadsoftDocument protocol = "OCI" xmlns="C" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
<sessionId xmlns="">TNN80U63D56CMMB8DV929UZT22177EAZ</sessionId>  
<command xsi:type="AuthenticationRequest" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
<userId>admin</userId>  
</command>
</BroadsoftDocument>'
reply: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>\n'

try:
    print('Starting stage httplib2')
    encoded_body = make_payload()
    http_agent = httplib2.Http(cache=None, timeout= 5, disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
    httplib2.debuglevel = 1
    response,response_body= http_agent.request('http://10.*.*.*:2208', \ method="POST", body=encoded_body, headers={'cache-control':'no-cache', 'Accept-Encoding':'ISO-8859-1', 'content-type':'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1','Accept': 'application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*', })
    print (response, response_body)
except:
```

....

Comment: Why are you sending `XML` data with a `GET` request. That's not supported? Or have you pasted in the response with the `GET` request as one clipboard object from wireshark here? I'm confused. Because in your `httplib2` example, you're `POST`:ing data...

Comment: Noted the get, modifed to post and posted same results. I originally had a POST.

Comment: More or less looks like a protocol issue, not a programming issue. I have no idea how this protocol works so I'm of no use.